# What is the max size for uploading a RingCentral custom greeting audio file?

Tags: ruby, ringcentral

When calling the RingCentral Create Custom Greeting API:

```
POST /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/greeting
```

I sometimes get the following error with larger files MP3 and WAV media files. Is there an official size limit?

```
HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large

{
    "errorCode": "AGW-413",
    "message": "Request entity too large",
    "errors": [

    ]
}
```

There's no limit specified in the API Reference or blog article:

API Reference:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefCreateUserCustomGreeting

I'm using the [`ringcentral_sdk` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/ringcentral_sdk) with the following code:

```
req = RingCentralSdk::REST::Request::Multipart.new(
  method: 'post',
  url: 'account/~/extension/~/greeting'
).
add_json({type: 'Voicemail', answeringRule: {id: '11111111'}}).
add_file(file)

res = client.send_request req

puts res.status
puts MultiJson.encode(res.body, pretty: true)
```

More is on this blog article:

https://medium.com/ringcentral-developers/updating-ringcentral-user-extension-greetings-using-the-rest-api-and-ruby-db325022c6ee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was informed there is currently a 1MB file size limit on this API.

I tested this with 0.4MB and 2.5MB WAV files here and confirmed that the smaller file worked and the larger file resulted in this error.

- https://www.mediacollege.com/audio/tone/download/

Other useful test files seem to be available here:

- https://www.audiocheck.net/testtones_highdefinitionaudio.php

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Python sample: https://github.com/tylerlong/ringcentral-python/blob/master/test/test_multipart_mixed.py

I also confirm that if the audio file is too large the operation will fail and you will get message `Request entity too large`.